Alone as an adverb or as an adjective

Alone, thought Bittering.

Does the word 'alone' describe Bittering as an adjective or his action of thinking as an adverb? Does the sentence mean that Bittering thought that he was alone or it means that he was thinking in loneliness?

Bittering thought of the adjective alone or the concept of being alone. He did not think in a lonely fashion. Perhaps his aunt was just widowed, and he thought "On, now alone."

Please give the source of the quotation!

In context, "alone" is being used as an adjective. The writer is saying that Bittering is or feels alone.
The comma indicates that that was what he was thinking, and not how he was thinking. If the sentence was, "Bittering thought alone", that would mean that he was thinking by himself. (It would be a strange thing to say. Unless you are mind readers, how would several people think together? But I suppose it might make sense in some context. Like if you were trying to say that he didn't know or care what others thought about the subject. Like, "Bittering was not subject to peer pressure. He thought alone." But even at that, that's just not something a fluent English speaker is likely to say.)
"Alone" can be an adverb. Like you can say, "He was living alone" or "He went on a trip alone".
